# SSRS Data Driven Subscriptions and Email Bounce Backs

Tags: ssrs-2008

Is there a way to recieve email bounce backs when a subscription failed? My current situation is my data drive subscriptions distrubute reports every Friday. Most of the time the email is sent out to users, but on random occasions, some users do not recieve the email. I am using ad email disbrution groups when sending out emails. I having a feeling, that some users in the email group are failing, but there's no way to identify which users faild via the SSRS logs....If there is a way, please let me know..Anyways, the from address is set by my server, but the email account is not a valided email account in exchange, so I can't view the email bounce backs. Is there another way to identify email bounce backs, maybe using "reply-to"?

Thank You,

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to make a valid email account for the sending email address.

Or if you can`t do that then you can re-configure the sending email address via the RS Configuration Manager (Email Settings -> Sender Address) to an address for which a valid email account exists.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Bounce tools from Boogie Tools.  They are great and highly configurable!
http://www.boogietools.com